# how to deal with inconsistent json fields in documents

Tags: json, mongodb, go

I currently have a large JSON file which has to be stored in the backend (mongodb & Go) and consumed in the front end. I was wondering whether the 3rd field of the documents should be something like "Sub category" instead of the sport name from the 2nd field or whether this is possible as I was thinking this maybe hard to model and deserialise in a backend language due to inconsistency?

sample:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55c"),
  "Sport" : "Athletics ",
  "Athletics" : {
    ["Men's Individual", "Women's Individual", "Mixed Relay"]
   }
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56c"),
  "Sport" : "Tennis",
  "Tennis" : ["Men's singles", "Women's singles", "Men's doubles", "Women's doubles", "Mixed doubles"]
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57c"),
  "Sport" : "Swimming",
  "Swimming" : {
    "Men" : ["4×100 m relay", "4×200 m freestyle relay"],
    "Women" : ["4×100 m relay", "4×200 m freestyle relay"]
  }
}
```

Comment: According to jsonlint the json is not valid.
Should be 
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55c"),
    "Sport": "Athletics ",
    "Athletics": [
        "Men's Individual",
        "Women's Individual",
        "Mixed Relay"
    ]
}

How do you create the json. Is it a different application that produce the documents?

Comment: Not answering you question, but may help  http://play.golang.org/p/2REBpnTkSh

Answer (score 3):

I'd agree with the little voice telling you to go with "Sub-Category" instead of trying to deal with inconsistent types. Also, you should combine the 'mens' and 'womens' subcategories in Swimming similar to how you do it it in Tennis and Athletics. This will let you make better use of encoding/json's (and mgo/bson's) mapping features, but I wouldn't call it a 'backend language' problem - consistent data types should make your js (and other client code) nicer, too!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    type Color struct {
        Space string
        Point json.RawMessage // delay parsing until we know the color space
    }
    type RGB struct {
        R uint8
        G uint8
        B uint8
    }
    type YCbCr struct {
        Y  uint8
        Cb int8
        Cr int8
    }

    var j = []byte(`[
        {"Space": "YCbCr", "Point": {"Y": 255, "Cb": 0, "Cr": -10}},
        {"Space": "RGB",   "Point": {"R": 98, "G": 218, "B": 255}}
    ]`)
    var colors []Color
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, &colors)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error:", err)
    }

    for _, c := range colors {
        var dst interface{}
        switch c.Space {
        case "RGB":
            dst = new(RGB)
        case "YCbCr":
            dst = new(YCbCr)
        }
        err := json.Unmarshal(c.Point, dst)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("error:", err)
        }
        fmt.Println(c.Space, dst)
    }
}
```